# Oracle combine multiple rows into one with distinct title

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this statement that combines multiple rows into one and then outputs it in the way I need the data:

```
 SELECT COURSES_ID, REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE
            , RTRIM
           ( xmlagg (xmlelement (c, CONDITION_TITLE || '' || REQ_TEXT || ''  ) order by   ORDER_NUM).extract ('//text()')
           , ',' ) AS REQTexts
    FROM   COS_REQUISITES
    WHERE COURSES_ID = '1175'
    AND REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE !=  'Corequisite'
    GROUP BY COURSES_ID, REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE;
```

Result:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ORDER_NUM ║ COURSES_ID ║        REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE         ║                                                                                                                                                           REQ_TEXT                                                                                                                                                            ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║         1 ║       1175 ║ Limitation on Enrollment            ║   With minimum grade of &quot;C&quot;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ║
║         2 ║       1175 ║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation ║ MATH 200 or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better  or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better or MATH 205 or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better or   or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better  or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Structure:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ORDER_NUM ║ COURSES_ID ║ CONDITION ║        REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE         ║                         REQ_TEXT                         ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║      1164 ║       1175 ║           ║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation ║ MATH 200 or equivalent college course with "C" or better ║
║      1165 ║       1175 ║           ║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation ║   or equivalent college course with "C" or better        ║
║      1166 ║       1175 ║  or       ║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation ║ MATH 205 or equivalent college course with "C" or better ║
║      1167 ║       1175 ║  or       ║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation ║   or equivalent college course with "C" or better        ║
║      1168 ║       1175 ║           ║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation ║   or equivalent college course with "C" or better        ║
║      1169 ║       1175 ║           ║ Limitation on Enrollment            ║   With minimum grade of "C"                              ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Wanted result:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation MATH 200 or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better  or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better or MATH 205 or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better  or equivalent college course with &quot;C&quot; or better Limitation on Enrollment With minimum grade of &quot;C&quot; ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I'm trying to avoid having to put this to a temp table or multiple views that would output this into one section.

I know it has bad data but I was told Garbage In, Garbage Out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Even with LISTAGG which doesn't allow for distinct as far as I can tell:

> SELECT COURSES_ID, LISTAGG(REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE || ' ' ||
>   CONDITION_TITLE || ' ' || REQ_TEXT, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY
>   ORDER_NUM) AS Title FROM  COS_REQUISITES WHERE COURSES_ID = '1175'
>   GROUP BY COURSES_ID;

Result:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             TITLE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Advisory on Recommended Preparation  MATH 200 or equivalent college course with "C" or better Advisory on Recommended Preparation    or equivalent college course with "C" or better Advisory on Recommended Preparation  or  MATH 205 or equivalent college course with "C" or better Advisory on Recommended Preparation  or    or equivalent college course with "C" or better Advisory on Recommended Preparation    or equivalent college course with "C" or better Limitation on Enrollment    With minimum grade of "C" ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Notice the REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE repeats, I only want it to show up once like the wanted result.  I can't modify the table to have them null due to this is a table being loaded dynamically and updated by someone else daily.

Comment: Wow, pseudographics! Long time no see! (Outside my Far Manager installation, that is.) I'll pretend that I am +1'ing a useful, well-written and illustrated question and not these beautiful tables alone. :)

Comment: lol thanks... I found this link helpful for doing this:
http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html
So copy data to excel put in table headers etc. Select Unicode art and your done.  Also as shown: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables
 and
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83009/do-you-know-any-online-tool-that-creates-ascii-tables-for-proper-use-on-stack-exc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit messy but should yield what you asked for

```
SELECT 
COURSES_ID, 
RTRIM ( xmlagg (xmlelement (c, REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE || '' || REQTexts || ''  ) order by   mino).extract ('//text()'), ',' ) AS REQTexts
FROM
(
SELECT 
COURSES_ID, REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE, MIN (ORDER_NUM) mino, 
RTRIM ( xmlagg (xmlelement (c, CONDITION_TITLE || '' || REQ_TEXT || ''  ) order by   ORDER_NUM).extract ('//text()') , ',' ) AS REQTexts
FROM COS_REQUISITES
WHERE COURSES_ID = '1175'
AND REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE !=  'Corequisite'
GROUP BY COURSES_ID, REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE
) 
GROUP BY COURSES_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using LISTAGG() function

Eg.: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

Hth

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't do distinct REQUISITE_TYPE_TITLE or I can't seem to figure out that part.